# How can I automate this task ? (automatic contouring for radiotherapy)

Tags: database, automation, deep-learning

I've just started my residency as a radiation oncologist. I have a little background in programming (Python, VBA).

I'd like your insights on an issue I have at work.

***The issue*** : For each patient, the radiation oncologist needs to do a contouring. Basically, he contours the main structures (like the aorta, the heart, the lungs, and so on) on a CT scan. This is essential for computing the spatial distribution of the radiations (because you want to avoid those structures). The contouring is done within a 3rd party software (called Isogray). The CT scans come from the hospital database and the radiation distribution is computed on another software.

It takes at least one hour to do a complete contouring. Multiply that by each patients (maybe a dozen per week) and by each oncologists (we are a team of 15 members) and you can see that it represents hundred (maybe even thousand) manhours every year.

There exists softwares that do this automatically, but the hospital doesn't want to rent/buy them. But, seriously, how hard can this be to do a little automation ? Can't I do this myself ?

***My plan of action*** : Here I'd like your insights. How can I automate this task ? The first thing is that I can't change anything within Isogray, so I need to do the automation externally. What I think I should do :

1. *Create a database of the historical contourings* : this means I need to be able to read what Isogray uses as an output files
2. *Design an automatic model* : I'm thinking deep learning models here. I don't know if there's anything more optimal to do than calibrating a deep learning model on the contoured CT scans I already have
3. *Create a little software* : based on the automatic model, the software will take a 'not contoured' Isogray file and turn it into a 'contoured' file. The oncologist only needs to load the new file into Isogray and validate the contouring

What do you think ? Do you see an easier way to do that ? I don't know anything about Isogray (I just know how to use it). Do you think this is doable? What information do I need before I start this project ?

Any insights will be welcomed :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood it is a problem of **semantic segmentation.**

You have an input image of N dimensions (or black and white) and you use the neural network to indicate which regions correspond to a specific organ.

You can use an architecture like the U-Net for this task: https://medium.com/@keremturgutlu/semantic-segmentation-u-net-part-1-d8d6f6005066

What I do not know is if the degree of reliability would be very high, that depends on many factors.

Neural networks look for differentiating patterns to discriminate zones, the first important component is shape and color. That is why it is more difficult when both the color and the shape are very different.

On the other hand you will need a lot of images but you can create a process called data-augmentation to generate more (artificial).

Another method that is currently used is to work in reverse, we know that the problem of image segmentation is difficult. But you can design a program that simulates real images where segmentation is known perfectly.

There are only some keypoints, I hope I have helped you.

**EDIT:**
Semantic segmentation in biomedic context: https://towardsdatascience.com/review-u-net-biomedical-image-segmentation-d02bf06ca760

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more background on the specifics on the contouring, especially given the fact that this is for medical diagnosis. Truthfully, I wouldn't try and automate this for liability reasons.

If you make an error someone it could cause a misdiagnosis, which as you already know can lead to numerous problems including lawsuits and death. The nice thing about 3rd party products is that it is already being tested robustly against numerous scenarios and approved for medical usage and liability reasons.

I'm pretty sure you could make a masters thesis doing something like this

With that being said, there is a nice [github repo](http://slicerrt.github.io/) for problems like this that I think you could potentially start generating ideas from.